# Regex match up to comma or strings

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I would like to match characters up to the first comma or after Esq.

```
Mr. Bob Smith, Esq., Fish Bowl Lane
Mr. Bob Smith, Fish Bowl Lane
```

I could not figure out how to lookaheads to produce the desired effect.

```
[^,]*
```

I expect to receive

```
Mr. Bob Smith, Esq.
```

and

```
Mr. Bob Smith
```

respectively.

Comment: It seems you wanted to capture everything before last appearance of a comma. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/7HGBjr/1) Also, hard coding a string in a regex isn't a good idea as it makes the solution very dependent on the input strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want to get a substring from the start of the string up to the first comma, and an optional `Esq.` substring after it:

```
^[^,]+(?:,\s*Esq\.)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3nDg9y/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `[^,]+` - one or more chars other than `,`
- `(?:,\s*Esq\.)?` - an optional non-capturing group (remove `?:` if your regex engine does not support non-capturing groups and only supports capturing ones) that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars
  - `Esq\.` - a literal `Esq.` substring.

Comment: Thank you. If I wanted to something else like PHD would the following be the best way? ^[^,]+(?:,\s\*Esq\.|,\s\*PHD\.)?

Comment: @Davin The best practice is to avoid alternative patterns that may match at the same location. Thus, I'd rather use `^[^,]+(?:,\s*(?:Esq|PHD)\.)?`.